# Writing and sharing Microfiction

Tags: resources, flash-fiction

So I've always enjoyed writing but never had the stamina to write a short story, let alone a novel. Mostly what I write these days is Micro-fiction (all short pieces of a couple hundred words, I've included one of my favorite pieces of mine below).

I was wondering if anyone else writes this, and whether they know of any communities built around it? Google hasn't been especially helpful, mostly because I don't know which forums are useful, helpful, and encouraging places and which are toxic, troll-ridden nightmares. Any suggestions would be very gratefully received!

Comment: Hi Maladictus! Welcome to Writers.SE! We're a Q&A site; feedback and sharing stories is beyond our scope here. Finding resources for a niche like microfiction or flash-fiction is on-topic, though; that's your primary question, so I've kept that (and removed the fiction piece). All the best!

Comment: That's fair, apologies for being off topic :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, others write microfiction. (I write 100-word stories.) There are several journals (online and print) that publish it. You don't ask about publishing, but you could start with [@Tiny_Text](https://twitter.com/Tiny_Text) and [100WordStory](http://www.100wordstory.org/). [Cupboard](http://www.thecupboardpamphlet.org/) publishes really interesting chapbooks of tiny fiction.

I don't know of any online communities, but they might be out there.

Answer (score 1):

It is worthwhile also searching for flash-fiction; although this can be up to 1000 words it will often be shorter. Also 'drabble' is another name for works of circa 100 word lengths. I myself write humorous flash-fiction, but don't really belong to any communities.